# Storing a value for confirmation in mobile

Tags: php, global-variables, laravel-5.4, vonage, sms-verification

i have a problem regarding logically storing the value of my `verification_id` to verify it in NEXMO. I declare it globally as `private $verification;` i use ajax, but when i call again the controller, the value that I've been initialize to the `$verification` variable is gone, so when I `var_dump($this->verification);` it is already null. Now i wan't a technique so that i can preserve the value of `$verification` value. I am using laravel 5.4

Here is what I've done:

```
private $client;
    private $verification;

    public function __construct() {        
        $this->client = app('Nexmo\Client');
    }
    public function mobile_verification($number) {                        

        $this->verification = $this->client->verify()->start([
            'number' => $number,
            'brand'  => 'MySite'
        ]);
        $request->session()->flash('mobile_verification', $this->verification);
    }

    public function check_verify($code) {        
        $value = $request->session()->get('mobile_verification', 'default');
        var_dump($value);
        //$this->client->verify()->check($this->verification, $code);
    }
```

Now as you can see, i have two functions named: `mobile_verification($number)` and `function check_verify($code)`. To clearly describe my problem, i have an `onclick` button to execute the two functions. Now first I've executed the function `mobile_verification($number)` after that, i want to store the value of  `$this->verification` as stated in my code, to be used on the next button onclick for the second function to fulfill this function : `$this->client->verify()->check($this->verification, $code);`

Any Suggestion ?. on whats the correct logic flow, so that i can get the value of `$this->verification` to run this on my second `onclick`

Comment: Are you trying to save a value that should be persistent across page requests? Then you should store the data in a session variable.

Comment: Here's the laravel doc about using sessions: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/session

Comment: Then you're not passing or defining the variable `$request` to/in that methods scope. I would recommend going through some Laravel tutorials (I  haven't used Laravel in a long time now). Look into dependency injection.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson i just copy paste from the laravel documentation, am i correct in storing it?

Comment: @MagnusEriksson please check my updated post. thats what i did. please help me